# Как выбрать случайный цвет в структуре Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

Есть структура Color (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color).

Как я могу выбрать в ней случайный цвет?

Comment: так вам нужен рандомный цвет или рандомное свойство?

Comment: рандомный цвет, но их же выбирать надо как свойства

Comment: хотя я почти уже догадался как. Осталось протестировать.

Comment: там в той структуре можно получить цвет исходя из rgba параметров

Comment: я про то же. Эти свойства статические - это просто какие то заранее созданные цвета. Мне кажется, вам ничего не стоит самому создать нужный вам цвет, не трогая эти свойства

Comment: Color RandomColor = Color.FromNonPremultiplied(rnd.Next(1, 255), rnd.Next(1, 255), rnd.Next(1, 255), 1);

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот вроде бы логично же, да? Что RGB рандомно, альфа будет всегда 1.
Но почему-то этот метод всегда конвертит RGB аргументы в 0.

Comment: То есть допустим R было 230, я засунул его в этот метод, но результат такой, как было бы при R = 0, всегда.

Comment: а, альфа должна быть 255.

Comment: Но это не меняет сути

Comment: что мешает написать просто `new Color(rnd.Next(1, 255), rnd.Next(1, 255), rnd.Next(1, 255));`?

Comment: так rnd это ведь не тип, это переменная. Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: я уже исправил комментарий

Comment: хм, так тоже можно, но я просто так начинал писать код. 
Но ваш вариант тоже не работает.

Comment: Цвет всегда черный, то есть все по нулям кроме альфы

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код, что вы пробуете. Есть подозрение, что вы делаете чт то не так

Comment: да, я что-то не так делал.. 
ваш код работает. Просто забыл отображать рандомный цвет вместо стандартного черного - проверял, правильно ли я вообще работал с методом Draw()

Comment: и мой код работал... где же я тогда что-то не так тогда делал? Простите за то что я вас напряг своей невнимательностью =)

Comment: ничего страшного, хорошо, что разобрались

Answer (score 0):

У структуры Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color есть несколько перегруженных конструкторов, для того, чтобы туда закинуть RGBA или RGB и получить цвет.
Также есть статический метод FromNonPremultiplied, который возвращает экземпляр структуры исходя из 3 или 4 параметров RGB / RGBA.

Можно сделать так:

```
Color RandomColor = Color.FromNonPremultiplied(rnd.Next(1, 255), rnd.Next(1, 255), rnd.Next(1, 255), 255);
```

Но лучше всего сделать так:

```
Color RandomColor = new Color(rnd.Next(1, 255), rnd.Next(1, 255), rnd.Next(1, 255));
```